# Calculate F values for large df2

Tags: r, statistics

My apologies if this is not the right place to be posting this question, it is related to numerical stability for stats calculations in R.

I am trying to calculate the F-value for very high values of df2 but it looks like it is numerically unstable:

```
nrange <- 350000:450000
f <- qf(1e-8, 8, nrange, lower.tail=FALSE)
plot(f ~ nrange)
```

looks like this: [image: graph of F-values]

Essentially at around `df2=400000` it is no longer accurate. The question is - does anybody know how I might get round this problem? For example, the F distribution can be approximated to two chi-squares (*e.g.* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution#Related_distributions_and_properties), and in the documentation for `qf` it says something about using `qchisq` for large d2. Actually `qchisq` does seem accurate at those values but it is not obvious to me how to implement this. For example

```
qf(0.05, 8, 100, lower.tail=FALSE)
```

and

```
(qchisq(0.05, 8, lower.tail=FALSE)/8) / (qchisq(0.05, 100, lower.tail=FALSE)/100)
```

do not give the same results.

So, the question is how do I get accurate F-values for large df2? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One useful thing about open source projects is that they are open source

```
fortune(250)

As Obi-Wan Kenobi may have said in Star Wars: "Use the source, Luke!"
   -- Barry Rowlingson (answering a question on the documentation of some implementation details)
      R-devel (January 2010)
```

If you look at the source code for `qf`

https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/nmath/qf.c

and specifically this bit

```
/* fudge the extreme DF cases -- qbeta doesn't do this well.
   But we still need to fudge the infinite ones.
 */

if (df1 <= df2 && df2 > 4e5) {
if(!R_FINITE(df1)) /* df1 == df2 == Inf : */
    return 1.;
/* else */
return qchisq(p, df1, lower_tail, log_p) / df1;
}
```

You will see that they are fudging values above 4e5. (ignoring `df2` entirely by assuming the same outcome as when df2 == Inf)

Comment: Haha thanks. I looked at the source and for the time being I will try using the method they use for `df < 400000` (calculating from the `qbeta`), but I am unsure what the consequences will be!